# Setting the capability 'applicationCacheEnabled' to 'false' using WebDriver DesiredCapabilities

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please help me, how to set the capability 'applicationCacheEnabled' to 'false'?
I have tried below, but seeing syntax errors.

```
DesiredCapabilities dc=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setCapability("applicationCacheEnabled", "false");
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Selenium version: 2.35.0,
Java version: 1.7.0_07

Comment: did you do any google ?or some initial homework?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527951/what-is-the-use-of-desiredcapabilities-in-webdriver check this

Comment: Did I do anything wrong in the above? Pls tell me what is the wrong thing in the above lines of code/tell me the syntax for setting capability?

Comment: any specific reason for only firefox? or chrome is also ok with you?

Comment: No, I need to run all my tests in FF only.. :(

Comment: There is no way to set for FF?

Comment: I have not worked with FF so I have to find it out. Can you go through the web driver site.?

Comment: Syntax looks good to me. If you paste syntax error, it will help others to help you.

Comment: @TDHM: Yes, the above syntax is correct. Got the answer(a simple mistake). The syntax error was due to calling the 'setCapability' method at the class level[directly under a class, outside a block] rather than within a block. I have moved the method invocation to some method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax in the question is absolutely correct.
The syntax error was due to calling the 'setCapability' method at the class level[directly under a class, outside a block] rather than within a block. I have moved the method invocation to some method.

Just adding one more point:

```
dc.setCapability("applicationCacheEnabled", "false"); can also be written as, 
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_APPLICATION_CACHE, false);
```