# Setting specific capabilities for selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to set some specific capabilities for a **Selenium Webdriver.**

In this example i want to change a `capability of the webdriver` for the Firefox browser. I'm trying to this in **Javascript**.

```
this.driver = new selenium.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
```

I tried things like calling `.withCapabilities()` but it is not working as i expected it and crashes the program.

In specific i want to set the '*acceptSslCerts*' capability to true because it is false in default.

Does anybody have an idea on how to this?
I'm not able to find anything in the [API reference](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html) or on the internet.

Comment: In Java, it can be done in the following way: cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true); Not sure how it works with Javascript

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities. This can help!!

Comment: Try setting webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs : true OR acceptSslCerts:true

Comment: http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index_exports_Profile.html

Comment: I am not sure about the last link you posted. There must be a general way to this because the chrome capabilties does not have a Profile class

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me, to set CORS in my chrome browser.

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

const capabilities = {
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['--disable-web-security', '--user-date-dir']
    }
}
let driver = new Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).forBrowser('chrome').build();
```

Answer (score 0):

For firefox, through **FirefoxProfile**, you can accept SSL certificate.

e.g FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
     firefoxProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true)

For googlechrome, through [DesiredCapability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527951/what-is-the-use-of-desiredcapabilities-in-selenium-webdriver), you can set the browser property.