# Is it required to set the DISPLAY for headless firefox browser on linux machine

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, xvfb, firefox-headless

I want to run the headless browser and below is the code for same.
However when i ran it. it shows "Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified"

```
try {
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.driver", "INFO");
profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.file", targetDir + File.separator + "firefoxSeleniumServer.log");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv;text/plain");
if(platform.equalsIgnoreCase("linux")) {
DesiredCapabilities desiredCap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",System.getProperty("user.dir")+ File.separator + "target");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/test/geckodriver/geckodriver");
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","/usr/bin/firefox/firefox");
desiredCap.setCapability("headless", true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

However when i set the display it shows unable to open firefox on DISPLAY:99

Also i tried setting the xvfb as well. But that also did not work.

As i am using gekco driver here, do i need to do some more configurations.

Comment: you do all of the work for creating a profile and capabilities, but then you instantiate FirefoxDriver() without using them!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to provide the `DesiredCapabilities` object as a parameter to the `FirefoxDriver` constructor:

References

- The [javadoc](http://javadox.com/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/2.53.0/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html#FirefoxDriver-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-) for `FirefoxDriver`.
- [What is the use of DesiredCapabilities in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527951/what-is-the-use-of-desiredcapabilities-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: For selenium3 above is deprecated. I tried with following as well but still facing the same issue.
    `binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/bin/firefox/firefox"));
    options.setBinary(binary);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);`

Comment: But did you try it with the deprecated class anyway?