# 'class' or 'interface' expected

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to start automating testing using Appium. I'm getting 'class' or 'interface' expected on my desired capabilities.

The code I'm using is below:

```
package tests;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class AppiumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "ZY224Gs7NG"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.vending");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        //Instantiate Appium Driver
        try {
            AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @glglgl Did you mean to say Shared? Mr comedian.

Comment: I know nothing of the DesiredCapabilities class but I suspect youre not supposed to try to call its constructor. There are static methods you would call  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527951/what-is-the-use-of-desiredcapabilities-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @JoeHz According to https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html#DesiredCapabilities--, there is nothing wrong doing so.

Comment: Can you post exact error message and mark the line which cause the problem?

Comment: @talex the line that is causing the problem are:  

caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");

it is complaining about a 'class' or 'interface' expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the above code in AppiumTest class use the code

cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.*PLATFORM_NAME*,MobilePlatform.*ANDROID*);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android device");

Always use device name as "Android device" and you don't need *PlatformVersion* line in your code and no need to give device id as well so also remove this line "*caps.setCapability("udid", "ZY224Gs7NG");*"

The other code looks great it should work with these changes.

Comment: Thanks I've changed my capabilities to look like the ones you provided!