# What is the difference between Desired Capabilities and system.set property in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please any one can describe the difference between 2, the main reason for deprecation..

Answer (score 1):

System.setProperty(key, value) is used for setting the property related to system. For ex. setting path of driver which we want to work with.

Desired Capabilities is used for setting the properties of browser only. For Ex Browser Name, Version, Platform , etc

Answer (score 0):

Set properties have 2 parameters one is which browser are you going to use and second is where is that driver path.

Desired capabilities -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527951/what-is-the-use-of-desiredcapabilities-in-selenium-webdriver   this link will help you to get idea